# Datediff in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, datediff

Before I start, I want to say sorry my question might be little silly since I'm a newbie for CR.

I put a datediff formula in Crystal Report ver 14.0.12,
and it returns incorrect result for some special cases.

### The formula is like below;

### DATEDIFF('M',{START_DATE},{END_DATE})

If the start date is 2018-05-01 and the end date is 2020-04-30, the result should be like '24',
but it returns '23'.
It seems if the date range is in the first or final day, it has above error.

In addition, I have another issue with other formula.

### I put below formula in order to get 'next date' of certain date field,

### DATE(YEAR({date_field}),MONTH({date_field}),DAY({date_field}+1))

and it has an issue when the date field is 'end date' of certain month.

For example, if the date field is 2020-03-31, expected result is 2020-04-01,
but my formula returns like '2020-03-01'.

Please let me know what should I do in order to get correct result.

Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to your `DateDiff()` function.

Did you possibly make a typo when asking your question?  The first argument for the function is the *intervalType* and is a String expression, therefore it should be contained within double quotes; you have single quotes in your question.  Using single quotes should throw a syntax error.  Also, the *intervalType* for Month should be expressed as a lowercase "m".

As for your issue with adding 1 day to a date, I would recommend using the `DateAdd(intervalType, nIntervals, startDateTime)` function to complete this task. Try this formula instead:

```
DateAdd("d", 1, {date_field})
```

However, be aware that this function will return a DateTime value, so if you want to remove the timestamp from the date that is returned, you will want to cast the entire function as a Date datatype using the `Date()` function as follows:

```
Date(DateAdd("d", 1, {date_field}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quote is fine. Source of the problem is that adding 1 to 31 is 32 (which gets wrapped back to 1 due to date logic).

Suggestion above to use DateAdd() is the correct solution.